# How to write solution for filtering reviews?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering

I am new to rails.I have model Review, with "text" column.I need to make a form where i fill a word and then on another page write all reviews which contain this word.How to filter it and write view if it can be 1 or can be a lot of reviews?Where i need pass filtering method(model or controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a form for search review eg: -

```
<%=form_tag filter_review_path do %>
  <%=text_field_tag :terms%>
  <%=submit_tag :submit%>
<%end%>
```

In reviews controller

```
def filter
  @filter_reviews = Review.where("LOWER(text) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:terms].downcase}%")
end
```

In routes.rb

```
get '/filter_review', to: "reviews#filter", as: :filter_review
```

In filter.html.erb show all filter_reviews

```
<%unless @filter_reviews.blank?%>
  <%@filter_reviews.each do |review|%>
     <%=review.text%>
     <%#=review.another_attribute%>
  <%end%>
<%else%>
  No review found
<%end%>
```